# For a function $f(x)$ find the value of the gradient $\frac{dy}{dx}$ given that: $\frac{dx}{dy}*\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =k\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> > Question: For a function $f(x)$ find the value of the gradient $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at the point where $y=2$ given that: $\frac{dx}{dy}*\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =k\frac{dy}{dx}$
> >
> > where $k$ is a constant and the gradient, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, is $1$ at the point $(0,1)$.

---

What I have thought of, I tried to form a differential equation such as

$$\frac{dx}{dy}*\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =k\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$ \frac{1}{y'} \times y'' = k \times y'$$

But I'm having trouble solving it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last equation write $$y''=k \,y'^2$$ So, let $p=y'$ and consider solving first $$p'=k p^2$$ which is separable $$p=-\frac 1{kx+c_1}$$ So, now $$y'=-\frac 1{kx+c_1}$$ which seems quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Call $\frac{dy}{dx} = u$ and then look at $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{du}{dx}$. This gives $\frac{d u}{dx} = k u^2$. You should then be able to calculate $\frac{1}{u} = -k x + C$ and determine the constant $C$ from $u|_{x=0} = 1$. Can then determine $y$ from $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{C - k x}$ (will introduce another constant, $D$, to be determined. You should then be able to determine what value of $x$ you need for $y = 2$ and determine $u = \frac{dy}{dx}$.